# asp.net website urlencode

Tags: asp.net, url-routing, urlencode

i made a website and i want to send mail to user.

i use url routing and if i use like this

```
localhost:1186/activate/johndoe@john.doe.com
```

i got iis server error because of dot signs. but if i don't use like this i can not get this email address from browser fully. 
i want that special chars in this email address must convert to html entities .

@ sign .(dot) sign and all of it . 
i want use it but not work

```
string email = "johndoe@john.doe.com";
string nemail = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(email);
```

it returns like

```
johndoe%40john.doe.com
```

but it must return like this

```
johndoe%40john(dotsignconvertedchars)doecom
```

not convert to dot signs ...

help me

Comment: i think after urlencodeing why dont you replace all dots with what ever you want for eg nemail.Replace(".","(dot)"); which would give you johndoe@john(dot)com

Answer (score 0):

i think after urlencodeing why dont you replace all dots with what ever you want for eg

```
 nemail.Replace(".","‌​(dot)");
```

which would give you johndoe%40john(dot)com

then after reciving it replace back

```
 nemail=nemail.Replace("(dot)",".");
 nemail=HttpUtility.UrlDecode(nemail);
```